# MySql - Select user name from two different tables in one query

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have 3 tables

- users table with user name and user id,
- leader board of users with user id and score
- leader board of likes with user id and numOfLikes

I want to select the name of the user with the most likes, and the name of the users with the most score. But my problem is that when I am writing the query I have duplicated `name` field there. What should I do?

Comment: use distinct keyword with name or group by

Comment: Do you only want the single user that has the most likes and score? Or do you want to return all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use following three tables in my query

1. usertable - contain username and userid
2. table2 - contain userid and score
3. table3 - contain userid and numOfLikes

To get details of user with max score use following

```
select usrtbl.username,usrtbl.userid,tbl2.score from  usertable usrtbl inner join table2 tbl2 on usrtbl.userid=tbl2.userid order by tbl2.score
desc limit 1
```

To get details of user with max number of likes use following

```
select usrtbl.username,usrtbl.userid,tbl3.numOfLikes from  usertable usrtbl inner join table3 tbl3 on usrtbl.userid=tbl3.userid order by tbl3.numOfLikes
desc limit 1
```

To get all in one query use following query

```
select usrtbl.username as 'user_with_max_score',usrtbl.userid as 'userid_of_user_with_max_score',
tbl2.score as 'max_score',usrtbl2.username as 'user_with_max_likes',usrtbl2.userid as 'userid_of_user_with_max_score' ,
tbl3.numOfLikes as 'max_likes' from  usertable usrtbl2 inner join table3 tbl3 inner join  usertable usrtbl inner join table2 tbl2 
on usrtbl.userid=tbl2.userid  and usrtbl2.userid=tbl3.userid order by tbl2.score desc,tbl3.numOfLikes desc
 limit 1
```

Comment: Yeah but how do you put them in one query?

Comment: @Babibu - do you want to find user with max score and user with max likes in one query?

Answer (score 2):

using alias may help you

```
SELECT a.id as id_a,
  b.id as id_b,
  c.id as id_c
from a
inner join b
  on a.id = b.a_id
inner join c
  on a.id = c.a_id
```

Comment: I think alias is exactly what I am looking for. But look at @Fathah Rehman P answer, how can you use alias to make with one query? My duplication is not in the statements(just using user id there) but in the data(in both results I have a user name and I can't use the key "name" twice)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `SELECT *`. You should specify the field names:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, li.numOfLikes FROM users u INNER JOIN likes li ON (u.user_id=li.user_id) ORDER BY li.numOfLikes

SELECT u.user_id, u.name, s.score FROM users INNER JOIN scores s ON (u.user_id=s.user_id) ORDER BY s.score
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select with **tablename**.name